# Scraping text using source Java - no text of reviews

Tags: java, html, web, urlconnection

I am trying to make an automated java program that will get the source code of a certain webpage, but the source code I am able to get with the automated program is different from the one I get when I right-click on the webpage.
Right now, based on the code that I found on the internet, this is my solution, which doesn't work. I need to get the text of the reviews, and the code below does not return it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(
            "http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g60745-d481776-r184086024-Prudential_Center-Boston_Massachusetts.html#REVIEWS");
    URLConnection spoof = url.openConnection();
    spoof.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
            "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.0;    H010818)");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            spoof.getInputStream()));
    String strLine = "";
    String finalHTML = "";
    // Loop through every line in the source
    while ((strLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        finalHTML += strLine+"\n";
    }
    System.out.println(finalHTML);
}
```

}

Comment: I suspect that you are getting raw HTML code before JS kicks in and changes content of your page. Maybe try using some WebDriver instead of URLConnection?

Comment: Can you explain better what is not working and what IS actually happening?

Comment: I get a portion of the html code, but not the explicit text for the reviews, nor a link to them, which is what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally cannot retrieve "the source code" of a page unless the page is a 1990's purely static HTML page.  The source code of a page will consist of HTML (or XML+XSLT) plus CSS, along with Javascript that modifies the DOM after the page has been loaded.

In addition, after the page has been loaded the DOM can continue to be modified in response to events, and can continue to fetch data from one or more servers via Ajax or even raw sockets.  So there is no such thing as "*the* source code" unless you mean just the originally transmitted HTML, CSS, Javascript and images.

Comment: If the reviews are being loaded via Ajax you will need to figure that out, determine the actual location (URLs) of the reviews and download them yourself.  This may or may not be simple, but will require analysis of the HTML/JS that you download as part of the initial GET request.